# Remove an item from object array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am fairly new mongodb, so if my question is not relevant please just ignore it.

I have a document as follows in MongoDB. I am trying to remove and item from files array.Not the first or last one. Those matching to query. That's why I googled a lot but couldn't find the solution yet. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

What I tried so far:

```
db.CustomerRequest.updateOne({
    "_id": ObjectId("64b7787dbe120dde9b70697a"),
    "proposal.id": "f197a152-26d1-465c-b533-7340c308a06d"
},
    {
        "$pull":
        {
            "proposal": [{ "files": [{ "src": "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/PNG Photo.png" }] }]

        }
    }
)
```

```
db.CustomerRequest.updateOne({
    "_id": ObjectId("64b7787dbe120dde9b70697a"),
    "proposal.id": "f197a152-26d1-465c-b533-7340c308a06d"
},
    {
        "$pull":
        {"files":  {"src": "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/PNG Photo.png"} }

        
    }
)
```

And I always got the response as follows. As a result array item is not removed.

{
"acknowledged" : true,
"matchedCount" : 1,
"modifiedCount" : 0
}

**Example JSON**

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b7787dbe120dde9b70697a"),
    "reqId" : "mysterious-monkey-39",
    "userName" : " ",
    "userId" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209",
    "mode" : 1,
    "type" : 1,
    "createDate" : ISODate("2023-07-19T05:45:33.314Z"),
    "autoCloseDate" : ISODate("2023-07-26T05:45:33.327Z"),
    "itemCat" : "Mice",
    "itemName" : "fasfdsadf dfsdfs",
    "zipCode" : " ",
    "quantity" : 1,
    "unit" : "piece(s)",
    "budget" : 0,
    "currency" : " ",
    "condition" : " ",
    "country" : " ",
    "state" : "Idaho",
    "urgency" : 1,
    "attachment" : [ ],
    "isClosed" : false,
    "detail" : "",
    "proposal" : [
        {
            "id" : "f197a152-26d1-465c-b533-7340c308a06d",
            "productName" : "asdASD",
            "quote" : 1000000,
            "promo" : "SDSFASD",
            "warranty" : "No",
            "warrantyPeriod" : null,
            "condition" : "Brand new",
            "freeShipping" : "No",
            "createDate" : ISODate("2023-07-20T18:34:29.788Z"),
            "organizationId" : ObjectId("61d7dcfe9beab44d14202b86"),
            "userId" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209",
            "isActive" : true,
            "description" : "",
            *"files" : [
                {
                    "src" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/PNG Photo.png",
                    "width" : 1500,
                    "height" : 500
                },
                {
                    "src" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/PNG Photo_Vertical.png",
                    "width" : 500,
                    "height" : 1500
                },
                {
                    "src" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/JPG Photo.jpg",
                    "width" : 1500,
                    "height" : 500
                },
                {
                    "src" : "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/JPG Photo_Vertical.jpg",
                    "width" : 500,
                    "height" : 1500
                }
            ]*
        }
    ]
}
```

I already wrote in problem description

Answer (score 0):

Remove an element in the nested `files` array.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("64b7787dbe120dde9b70697a"),
  "proposal.id": "f197a152-26d1-465c-b533-7340c308a06d"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "proposal.$[].files": {
      "src": "5989ace4-1355-4af6-bef6-0b38cf906209/PNG Photo.png"
    }
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0_5GAVKbIOR)